# 'Not enough space to show ad' using Android and AdMob

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I used the code provided at the [AdMob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdMob) site.

Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/grid780" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/icon1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:background="@drawable/previous"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/next"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/moderase"
    />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/modpencil"
    />
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

But the [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file) shows:

> E/Ads(4244): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <432, 576>

It seems like the layout is creating issue. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that there's not enough width for the adview. Remove the left/right padding from your root `RelativeLayout`.